# pyspark streaming: failing to execute rdd.count() on workers

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, spark-streaming

I have a pyspark streaming job doing something along these lines:

```
def printrddcount(rdd):
    c = rdd.count()
    print("{1}: Received an RDD of {0} rows".format("CANNOTCOUNT", datetime.now().isoformat()) )
```

and then:

```
...
stream.foreachRDD(printrddcount)
```

From what I get, the printrdd function will be executed within the workers
And, yes, I know it's a bad idea to do a print() within the worker. But that's not the point.
I'm pretty sure this very code was working until very recently.
(and, it looked differently, because the content of 'c' was actually printed in the print statement, rather than just collected, and then thrown away...)

But now, it seems that (all of a sudden?), then rdd.count() has stopped working ans is making my worker process die saying:

```
UnpicklingError: NEWOBJ class argument has NULL tp_new
```

full (well, python only) stacktrace:

```
Caused by: org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/hdp/current/spark2-client/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 163, in main
    func, profiler, deserializer, serializer = read_command(pickleSer, infile)
  File "/usr/hdp/current/spark2-client/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 54, in read_command
command = serializer._read_with_length(file)
  File "/usr/hdp/current/spark2-client/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 169, in _read_with_length
    return self.loads(obj)
  File "/usr/hdp/current/spark2-client/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 454, in loads
    return pickle.loads(obj)
UnpicklingError: NEWOBJ class argument has NULL tp_new
```

The line where it fails is, indeed, the one saying rdd.count()

Any idea why rdd.count() would fail?
If something is supposed to be serialized, it should be the rdd, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. I investigated a bit further.
There's nothing wrong with rdd.count()

Only thing wrong is that there is another transformation along the pipe that somehow 'corrupts' (Closes? Invalidates? Something along those lines) the rdd.
So, when it gets to the printrddcount function it cannot be serialized any more and gives the error.

The issue is within a code that looks like:

```
...
log = logging.getLogger(__name__)
...
def parse(parse_function):
    def parse_function_wrapper(event):
        try:
            log.info("parsing")
            new_event = parse_function(event)
    except ParsingFailedException as e:
        pass
    return new_event
return parse_function_wrapper
```

and then:

```
stream = stream.map(parse(parse_event))
```

Now, the log.info (tried a lot of variations, in the beginning logging was within an exception handler) is the one creating the issue.
Which leads me to say that, most probably, it is the logger object that cannot be serialized, for some reason.

Closing this thread myself as it has actually nothing to do with rdd serialization; and most probably not even with pyspark even.